# Using serde_json to deserialize from Vec<u8>

Tags: rust, lifetime, serde

We have a vector `Vec<u8>` that we want to deserialize to a type `T`. The minumum reproducing example we could come up with is

```
fn wrapper<'de, T>(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Result<T, serde_json::Error>
where
    T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    serde_json::from_slice::<'de, T>(&vec)
}
```

However, the compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `vec` does not live long enough
   --> src/wrapper.rs:128:38
    |
124 | fn wrapper<'de, T>(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Result<T, serde_json::Error>
    |            --- lifetime `'de` defined here
...
128 |     serde_json::from_slice::<'de, T>(&vec)
    |     ---------------------------------^^^^-
    |     |                                |
    |     |                                borrowed value does not live long enough
    |     argument requires that `vec` is borrowed for `'de`
129 | }
    | - `vec` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Since we have full ownership of the vector and the type `T` doesn't have a reference to any of the original data (e.g. it could be a number or a `String`), I'm stumped as to what is causing this error.

I still get the same error with the following changes:

- `serde::Deserialize<'static>`
- `serde::Deserialize<'de> + 'static`
- `serde::Deserialize<'de> + 'de`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with

```
fn wrapper<T>(vec: Vec<u8>) -> Result<T, serde_json::Error>
where
    T: for<'de> serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    serde_json::from_slice(&vec)
}
```

From Rust's [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds)

> Trait bounds may be higher ranked over lifetimes. These bounds specify a bound that is true for all lifetimes.

So the solution here was to have the trait being bound for all lifetimes, not a specific one. Including the lifetime of the function itself, which is the lifetime of `vec`.

Comment: This isn't wrong, but serde provides a trait that does this for you: `DeserializeOwned`. See explanation in the [serde docs for deserializer lifetimes](https://serde.rs/lifetimes.html#trait-bounds).

Comment: I didn't know about this trait! That's pretty sweet. I also really like their explanation of control by callee or caller.